# Make a list from a set of documents in MongoDB collection

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection `D1` like this:

```
{
   _id: 0,
   author:Jose Fernandez,
   handle: Md8937,
   reference: [
     { item_id: 43, author: Alberto Perez, year: 1910, context: some text },

     { item_id: 44, author: Lucas Leys, year: 1990, context: some text },

     { item_id: 45, author: Johan Ortiz, year: 2005}
   ]
}
{
   _id: 1,
   author: Ramiro Ramirez,
   handle: Gh8765,
   reference: [
     { item_id: 68, author: Mats Valk, year: 1993, context: some text },

     { item_id: 74, author: Robert Lucas, year: 1976, context: some text },

     { item_id: 80, author: Mark Ljumberg, year: 2005, context: some text}
   ]
}
{
   _id: 2,
   author: Feliks Zemdges,
   handle: Yt4573,
   reference: [
     { item_id: 1, author: Gan Zandhi, year: 2015},

     { item_id: 2, author: Dayan Wojung, year: 1976, context: some text },

   ]
}
```

I need to make a python list from that contains all `handle` values for every object in the collection like this:

```
handles=["Md8937","Gh8765","Yt4573"]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a cursor and append each item as required.

```
import pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient(")['mydatabase']

cursor = db.mycollection.find({}, {'handle': 1, '_id': 0})
handles = []
for item in cursor:
    if 'handle' in item:
        handles.append(item['handle'])

print (handles)
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gen_handles.py", line 13, in <module>
    handles.append(item['handle'])
KeyError: 'handle'`

Comment: That means your data doesn't look like the data you provided. I've added some checking to the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where values for handle are unique ( and your collection is not so big) you can also use:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
CON = MongoClient()
db = CON['YourDatabase']      
coll = db['YourCollection']
handles = coll.distinct('handle')
```